# What could be a way to improve my English writing?

Tags: academic-writing, grammar

I know there are general recommendations to improve English writing skills but I wonder if anyone could suggest hyper-personalized ways for me. I studied English as a second language from middle school and also took some serious exams like TOEFL and GRE. I have been working at English speaking environment for almost 5 years but doing no specific attempt to further improve my English.

A few days ago, I submitted a scientific article to a conference without taking proofreading from native speakers. Two reviewers pointed out the manuscript requires polishing in terms of English and I began to wonder which specific aspects I'm lacking to be a good English writer. I hope there is a super kind expert who can recommend me what I should do. The following is a portion of text that I wrote:

> On top of the renowned real world driving datasets, synthetic datasets are extensively utilized in our experiments. Employing synthetic dataset is becoming inevitable for training a deep neural network as it provides an effective and economic way to generate massive amount of data even with the accurate ground truth information. Using an open source 3D engine Blender, we implemented several virtual road driving scenes in various qualities, in terms of reality and number of objects (such as pedestrians and vehicles) in the scene.

> While high quality scenes helped us to maintain smaller domain gaps to real world data, simpler scenes contributed to effciently increasing the diversity of the dataset. To ameliorate the lighting estimation capability of our network, we render the synthetic images as triplets. The two images in a triplet share each intrinsic component with a reference image in the triplet. In other words, one image has the same albedo as the reference while the shading is different and the other vice versa. We assume the network can distinguish the shading from actual differences in reflectance by exploiting this dataset. The following is the algorithm that we used to generate the triplet inputs:

Comment: Are you asking about your writing in general, or that specific section? Writing critiques are off-topic here, but we can use that section as an example and give you more general advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am a non native English speaker too. The most useful suggestion I can give is to read a lot in English, especially papers in your own field (IT I suppose). You probably do already. Try also reading again after you have absorbed the meaning of the document and this time check how sentences are structured. Is that how you would have done it? What sounds better?
Do you think in English? Your work is good but reading your excerpt it sounds sometimes like a translation from another language.

This is my take at polishing your passage:

> <s>On top of</s> Expanding the renowned real world driving datasets, synthetic datasets are extensively <s>utilized</s> applied in our experiments. Employing synthetic datasets is becoming <s>inevitable</s> imperative <s>for training</s> to train a deep neural network as it provides an effective and <s>economic</s> cost-effective way to generate massive amount of data  <s>even with the</s> still based on an accurate <s>ground</s> foundation <s>truth</s> of real information. Using an open source 3D engine, Blender, we implemented several virtual road driving scenes <s>in various qualities</s> with different degrees of complexity in terms of <s>reality</s> realism and number of objects (such as pedestrians and vehicles) in the scene.

Am not really sure what you mean with "in terms of reality" so I may have misunderstood it.

Comment: In addition to popular real-world driving datasets, synthetic datasets are extensively utilized in our experiments. Thus, employing synthetic data-set is inevitable for training on a deep neural network, an effective and economic way to generate massive amount of data (even with the accurate ground truth information?) Using the open source 3D engine Blender, we implemented several virtual road driving scenes of various qualities, such as pedestrians and vehicles.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As F1Krazy said, writing critiques are off-topic here, but I think it will be helpful to fix a few small things in the passage you submitted, just to give you an idea of what grammar skills you should work on.

Here are my corrections:

> Employing **a** synthetic dataset is becoming inevitable for training a deep neural network, as it provides an effective and economic way to generate **a** massive amount of data even with the accurate ground truth information.

I have highlighted where you should place indefinite articles ("a") in this sentence, and I also added a comma for readability.

*Grammar rule of note:* **Placement of articles.** Whenever you have a verb followed by a singular noun ("he ran a business", "she washed the dog", etc.) you *must* separate the verb from the noun with an article, otherwise the sentence sounds incoherent ("he ran business", "she washed dog" would be examples of incorrect sentence grammar).

> While high quality scenes helped us to maintain smaller domain gaps **when compared to** to real world data, simpler scenes contributed to eff**i**ciently increasing the diversity of the dataset.

Here I have added a small phrase to make that first clause more readable, and also corrected a typo in the spelling of "efficiently."

*Grammar rule of note:* **Comparison phrases.** When you are comparing two concepts in English, you typically should have some kind of flowing phrase in between, such as "when compared to", "as opposed to", etc. For example, if I was saying, "I am better at chess when compared to my brother," it would sound odd if I removed the flowing phrase and it just became "I am better at chess to my brother." However, instead of adding this "flow phrase," you can also employ "than," and the sentence can become: "I am better at chess than my brother." This would be just as grammatically correct.

Comment: It's too bad that I can't select the both replies as the answers. Thank you Sciborg. The concept of article doesn't exist in my mother tongue so it's like an endless burden for me to bear...